# Access google+ user profile ID

Tags: google-plus

I need to access job title from Google+ profiles and I can do it with specific id.
but I want to access about 100 profiles and read their job titles without any user id.
how can I do it??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [plus.people.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) API to search for people to get their ids then could get their profile.

In JavaScript:

```
gapi.client.plus.people.search(
  { query: 'Gus', 
    fields: 'items/id'
  }).execute(
      function(resp){
        for (var i=0; i < resp.items.length; i++){
          gapi.client.plus.people.get(
            { userId: resp.items[i].id, 
              fields: 'displayName,organizations(title)'}).execute(
                function(resp){
                  console.log(resp)
                });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks.Do you know what is :  Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(accessMethod)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setTokenServerEncodedUrl(tokenServerEncodedUrl)
    .setClientAuthentication(clientAuthentication)
    .setRequestInitializer(requestInitializer)
    .build();

Comment: Looks like client library initialization for Java. Personally, I prefer to build credentials as: GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build();